# Find ID in list of inserted records using a key.

Tags: apex

Ok, I think I need to using map for this but don't quite now how to accomplish.

Hopefully this makes sense to someone else!

Here is a basic example as my actual code is too involved to understand. 
FYI, I am just using the terms Parent, Child, and Orphan to make the record relationship easier to understand.

```
List<Parent__c> pList = new list<Parent__c>(); 
pList.add(new Parent__c(
    Name = 'Parent 1'
    Match_Field__c = '123'
));
pList.add(new Parent__c(
    Name = 'Parent 2'
    Match_Field__c = '456'
));
insert pList;

List<Child__c> cList = new list<Child__c>();

For(Unclaimed__c unc:uncList){ //list of unclaimed records
cList.add(new Parent__c(
    Name = 'Child 1'
    Parent__c = ***this is where I'm stuck***
     //need to use a custom field from unc and look for a match in the list of parents. 
     //I'm matching off the Match_Field__c from Parent. Need to get the Salesforce ID of Parent. 
));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, there's two ways to approach this - one all in Apex and one using the database's native External Id mechanism. Which to choose just depends on the structure of your code.

In Apex, as you're creating your parent records, you can be populating a `Map<String, Parent__c>` with the relevant values:

```
Map<String, Parent__c> pMap = new Map<String, Parent__c>(); 
pMap.put(
    '123', 
    new Parent__c(
       Name = 'Parent 1'
       Match_Field__c = '123'
    )
);
// and so on...
insert pMap.values();
```

Then when you create `Child__c` records:

```
cList.add(new Child__c(
    Name = 'Child 1'
    Parent__c = pMap.get('123').Id
));
```

But if you're not creating all of the data at once - that is, if you need to associate `Child__c` records with *existing* `Parent__c`s based on that match field - you can use the technique described in [Relating Records by Using an External ID](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_nested_object.htm):

```
cList.add(new Child__c(
    Name = 'Child 1'
    Parent__c = new Parent__c(External_Id__c = '123') 
));
insert cList;
```

Note that the field *must* be an External Id for this to work.

If the field is not an External Id, you would need to accumulate a Set of the string values you want to match against, perform a query against `Parent__c` using `WHERE Match_Field__c IN :mySetOfValues`, build a `Map<String, Parent__c>` using those values, and write logic to handle any duplicate values. Then use the Map to access the right parent Id.

Answer (score 0):

So, the key you want to use in your example is `Match_Field__c`.

You are correct in thinking that a Map can help you here. Specifically a `Map<String, Account>`

The general idea is that you iterate over `plist` to populate this map

```
Map<String, Account> myMap = new Map<String, Account>();
for(Account parent :plist){
    myMap.add(parent.Match_Field__c, parent);
}
```

Then, when you iterate over your `Unclaimed__c` list, you `get()` from the map to obtain the parent account record.
Maps store *references* to many non-primitive data types, like `SObject`, so when you insert your parents, the reference to that parent account stored in the map will also be updated with the newly assigned Id.

```
Parent__c = myMap.get(unc.Match_Field__c).Id
```